# beautifulsoup selenium soup find_all to select parent and then children

Tags: selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I’m a bit stuck I have the below for loop and have spent days getting it to work and am supper stuck on getting data from the html code at the bottom doing it by hand is not a option as there will be some 1000+ to gather.

```
import re 

from selenium import webdriver 

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

from time import sleep 

from random import randint 

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 

  

# login credentials 

username="xxxxxxx" 

password="xxxxxxx" 

  

url_subcategorise_list={ 

    "https://www./search/all-items?id=C99" 

} 

# url_subcategorise_list.add("") 

# print(url_subcategorise_list) 

  

# initialize the Chrome driver 

chromedriver_path="C:\\Users\\xxx\\projects\\web_scrapper\\web_scrapper.exe" 

service=Service(chromedriver_path) 

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service) 

  

url="https://www.xxxx.co.uk" 

driver.get(url) 

  

# at login page 

# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field 

driver.find_element(By.ID, "username").send_keys(username) 

# find password input field and insert password as well 

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='password']").send_keys(password) 

# click login button 

driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='submit']").submit() 

  

# start driver get 

  

#    driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=service) 

for link in url_subcategorise_list: 

    driver.get(link) 

    get_url=driver.current_url 

    print("The current url is:"+str(get_url)) 

    soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser') 

    print(soup) 

    driver.quit() 

  

# driver.implicitly_wait(10) 

  

# now leaving site 

# driver.close()
```

Below is part of the pages html I need to select data from, I’ve selected the next parent div that covers all the data I need:

```
<div class="md-modal md-effect-12" id="modal-promo"> 
    <div class="md-content"><h3>75mm(3") NO.1 POZI S/DRIVER</h3> 
        <div> 
            <div class="dninfo pure-g"> 
                <div class="pure-u-1-2 img both"><img class="pure-img" 
                                                      src="/info/images/by-supplier/W72/6021.jpg"></div> 
                <div class="bullets pure-u-1-2">75mm(3") NO.1 POZI S/DRIVER</div> 
            </div> 
            <input class="md-close" type="button" value="Close"></div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

I need to get the data from the following text:

```
<h3>75mm(3") NO.1 POZI S/DRIVER</h3> 
<div class="bullets pure-u-1-2">75mm(3") NO.1 POZI S/DRIVER</div>
```

And the only identifier there is /info/images/by-supplier/W72/6021.jpg

```
links = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['md-effect-12'])
for link in links:
    divcollector.add(link.get("div"))
```